# HTTP_HOST changing in functions.php

Tags: functions, nginx, virtual-hosts

I have getting variable results from the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable in the `functions.php` file of our child theme.

We are running WordPress 3.5.2 on NGINX with PageLines 2.4 as our parent theme and a handful of plugins that I can detail if necessary. Our virtual host is set to answer to:

```
*.salesgenie.com
```

As we have several private label subdomains that will change the branding of the site. `www.salesgenie.com` will be the generic domain but `att.salesgenie.com` is an example of a branded subdomain.

I need to be able to detect the subdomain the client calls with which I am trying to get with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. The issue is that `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is accurate the first time a client comes to their domain but reverts to the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` value after that either on page reload or navigation to any other page. Any ideas why this might happen or how to work around it?

To test this I've got a function logging the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to a cookie called CMSCookie and you can test it by going to `[cms.salesgenie.com][1]` (the CNAME is working) and both variables will read `cms.salesgenie.com`.  But if you modify your host file to point `att.salesgenie.com` at `54.208.87.200` then you can test `att.salesgenie.com` and the cookie will be correct the first time you hit a page, but if you reload, both server name and host will be `cms.salesgenie.com`

Comment: WordPress only changes the value of `HTTP_HOST` in the `\wp-includes\ms-settings.php` file. Specifically, it strips the port if `:80` or `:443` are in the url. If your parent theme and the plugins are not changing this value, this may not be a WordPress question.

Comment: Well I'll copy our installation to our test environment and see if switching themes or disabling plugins does anything.

Comment: Alrighty then.  It is a PageLines theme issue since when I switch to TwentyTwelve I get the proper value for HTTP_HOST.

Comment: I only scanned the code, but look a the result of `pl_get_uri( true );`

Comment: It's behaving the same as HTTP_HOST.  Fine on the first visit to the url, but then rest to SERVER_NAME after that.

Comment: I didn't see any code that was changing the value of `HTTP_HOST`. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP's comment:

> It is a PageLines theme issue since when I switch to TwentyTwelve I get the proper value for `HTTP_HOST`